# Use of "echo" or "print" statement in php is disturbing the appearance of website

Tags: php, css

Hello I've working on a project just for the practice of my newly acquired knowledge of web developing.

First I designed the UI with css and then I am doing the back end.
But here I am facing a weird kind of issue.

When I am using echo or print statement in php, the UI is getting completely disturbed.

Without echo:

[image]

[image]

With echo

[image]

[image]

[image]

As I am certainly new to web developing, I can't understand what is causing this and how do I solve this. I just hope I don;t have to write the whole css again.

Or is there anything wrong with javascript?
I am totally clueless, and I can't find any issue like this on the web.

Comment: **Don't post code as images.** Code is text so copy/paste it into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the problem is, that you echo the script BEFORE the whole HTML body.
You should place it inside `<head>` or inside `<body>` but definitely not before the opening `<html>` tag.

Also using `echo` on multiple lines does not print out the result on multiple lines... so I guess your JS would be all in 1 line, which can also cause a problem with the script itself.

If the problem persists after you do this, there may be other problems :)

Comment: Thanks. Look, as I mentioned I am just learning this, and I didn't know that I had to write that script inside <html> tag. I was just following the tutorials. But still, thaks a lot. Should I delete the question?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you should accept it :) If you are embarassed of your question, you can delete it of course :)

Comment: I tried to accept the answer, it said, I have to wait for 4 minutes for accepting the answe. And yeah, I feel a bit embarassed.

Comment: @SamarpitShrivastava - No need to feel embarrassed. All of us have been a beginner at some point.

Comment: no need to be embarassed, I just meant it as a joke :) There is nothing wrong with asking questions, as long you spent at least some time trying first